# Firebase Auth Quickstart requires Kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dependencies

When you download this app source
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/auth and try to compile it in Android Studio with Java as your primary language, various references to Kotlin stops it from compiling...

I have no plan to switch to Kotlin soon, but now I have to fight with Kotlin dependencies and plugins or manually remove all the relevant lines.

Is there a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "fight"? The sample is a Gradle project. If it doesn't build with Gradle out of the box, you need to file a bug for the sample. The Kotlin plugin is bundled with Android Studio, but even if you disable it, the project should still build.

Comment: The sample now comes with Kotlin code mixed in between the java. So I am forced to use Kotlin or at least need to tolerate it hanging around in my code, for example, EntryChoiceActivity. I want to switch to Kotlin or mix Kotlin and Java when I choose to, but not be forced to do so just to get/use Firebase sample code.

Comment: It's not hanging around in your code, it's hanging around in the code of a sample project developed by other people. No one is forcing you to use Kotlin in your project, or to use this sample. What "better solution" are you looking for?